# Does AWS NLB Supports mutual SSL?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-nlb

I have an NLB with TLS listener and backend TLS protocol Target group. My backend server is Rabbitmq and SSL enabled with certificate peer verification.

When I try to connect to the server directly from the app it's working and via NLB it's showing SSL handshake failure.

Comment: NLB will support this. NLB won't even try to verify certs. It's probably some form of configuration error on the server. Try using `openssl` to connect to the server/port and see if it provides any additional information: `openssl s_client -connect hostname:1234 -prexit`

Comment: Agree that NLB won't try to verify cert's, But will it pass root CA and CA both for hand shake to backend. Server config should not be issue as it's working when connected directly. Openssl connect also showing same error in log handshake failed and it's closing connection via lb.